# Docker: mounting volumes from other docker service (not container)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have two hosts that run docker service on each host.

Container from host A wanted to uses volume that created from host B.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noops, both services should be on the same host but there is one thing you can do.

> All reused data volumes are mounted on the same paths as in the source
>   service. Containers must be on the same host in order to share
>   volumes, so the containers of the new service will deploy to the same
>   nodes where the source service containers are deployed.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/volumes/

Possible solution:

1. mount volume to a host directory
2. sync that directory between your nodes

You can use [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html) to sync directories on all nodes, i have used it myself works fine